# command-line argument conventions for stdin, stdout

Tags: command-line, stdout, stdin, conventions

I'm writing a command-line tool that takes a file and modifies its contents. I would like the user interface to be as canonical as possible. So far, I have

```
$ foobar -h
usage: foobar [-h] [--version] [infile] [outfile]

Some help text.

positional arguments:
  infile         input LaTeX file (default: stdin)
  outfile        output LaTeX file (default: stdout)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version, -v  show program's version number and exit
```

but I noticed that tools like `sed` *always* print to `stdout`, unless given the `-i` parameter in which case the input file is modified in-place. Is this a common Unix convention?

Comment: No, there is no convention. It is good to use similar options as you find in similar tools, but there is no convention. And in past there were more problems: it was important to distinguish: *modify in place*, with *copy, modify, substitute the file*

Comment: There are different alternative conventions. It depends on how you will use your program and personal preference. Many programs write to stdout and read from either stdin or a file to allow creating a pipeline, e.g. `sed command inputfile | sort | uniq -c`. Some programs allow the special file name `-` for stdin or stdout when used as input or output file name respectively. In-place editing like `sed`'s option `-i` can be problematic because you might lose your original input in case of an error.

Comment: One interesting case is where you want to process multiple input files to one output file. That makes positional args useless. The usual method there is to have an option like `-o outFile`, but default to stdout so it can be redirected or piped at the command line.

Comment: You can make your program simpler (and more "canonical") by getting rid of the `infile` and `outfile` arguments. Simply let read from stdin and write to stdout. The user can use it as `prog <file1 >file2`, which would also make clear that `file2` really is an output, and not another input as with `cat file1 file2`, and **will save users from inadvertently overwriting files**. The `-i` option of sed is broken, and you should not bother with it; you can easily achieve the same effect with `prog <file >file.new && mv file.new file || rm file.new`.

Comment: @Bodo No, `sed -i` does **NOT** really edit the file in place, and will **NOT** trash the original input in case of an error (it will only replace the original at the end, after everything has succeeded, with an atomic `rename(2)` operation). The problem with `sed -i` is that **1.** it doesn't preserve the file's inode and most of its metadata, **2.** it will fail if you don't have write permissions to the containing directory **3.** it will break sym- and hard-links.

Comment: @user414777 I know how `sed -i` works and that the contents of the file will be either the old or the new contents. But there are other errors possible, e.g. an error in the commands passed to `sed`. In this case the user cannot simply repeat the `sed` with the correct command if the data is already modified. Or a script, that uses `sed -i` and somehow fails after this command, may produce different results when repeated as a whole. Additionally it is not clear how the OP would implement similar behavior in his tool.

Comment: @user414777 Of course there are use cases where it's necessary to modify an original file instead of creating a modified copy. Without knowing the purpose of the OP's tool I cannot give any specific advice. When in doubt, I recommend against modifying or replacing the original input file if possible.

Comment: Which is exactly [my point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612207/command-line-argument-conventions-for-stdin-stdout?noredirect=1#comment1143175_612207) ;-) But your comment suggesting (whether intended or not) that `sed -i` may trash the file in case of error wasn't that far-fetched, considering that it was *exactly* what `perl -i` (which was supposed to be similar to `sed -i`) was doing [until quite recently](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.28.0/pod/perldelta.pod#In-place-editing-with-perl-i-is-now-safer). That's why I felt the need to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

`-i` is `sed`-specific. For, for example, `awk` it would be `-i inplace`, and many others don't even support in-place actions.

There are a number of conventions. The most important is, that if no input is given, use STDIN, and if no output is given use STDOUT. But that one you already do.

In general, most programs treat a list of files on the command line as files that must be read. Many programs use `-o filename` to indicate that the output should go to `filename`.  GNU seems to like `--output` for this as well.

If you want to explicitly use STDIN or STDOUT, `--` seems more or less the standard way of specifying that.

But then, there are many programs that do not follow this convention. Some use the last positional argument for the output. Some us `--` to indicate that the rest of the command line only contains files, and some (like `dd`) have created their own standard.

So, if I were you, I'd stick with `-o` *and* `--output` for the output file and use `--` for STDIN or STDOUT. And write a clear man page, so your program becomes predictable.